# Round Border around text

Tags: html, css

How can i apply the effect shown in the image using css

```
<div class="textstyle"><b>Sales Cash Invoice</b></div>
```

[image: text]

Comment: In the future, these sort of questions can be answered by opening your browser's developer tools and seeing the styles attached to a given element.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HTML:

`<div class="textstyle">Sales Cash Invoice</div>`

CSS:

```
.textstyle {
    background-color: gray; /* Changing background color */
    font-weight: bold; /* Making font bold */
    border-radius: 20px; /* Making border radius */
    width: auto; /* Making auto-sizable width */
    height: auto; /* Making auto-sizable height */
    padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px; /* Making space around letters */
    font-size: 18px; /* Changing font size */
}
```

If you want to add font, just add a new line to css `font-family: font_name;`. I can't do that because i don't know what font is on the image.

For a more precise colors, use [Color Picker](http://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp).

Answer (score 2):

```
.textstyle {
  background: #CDCDCD;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

Answer (score 0):

another method would be to use `background-clip` and `border-radius`

```css
.rounded-bg {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />


<p class="rounded-bg">Sale Cash Invoice</p>
```

[image]