# How do I create an oval around text in CSS?

Tags: html, css, hover, overlay

I need to create the image below using css. 
[image]
But this is what I get
[image]
Everytime you hover over an image the overlay disappears, which I've done. 
But the middle image contains text with an oval around it (Shop Now) and I can't get the oval to be positioned correctly.
Here's my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9f6xat3f/1/

Here's some of the css I have:

```
.trending-button1{  
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    }

    /*banner overlay*/
    div.homepage-popular-categories {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    div.homepage-popular-categories p {
      margin: 0;
      /*display: block;*/
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      color: #eeeeec;
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      transition: opacity 0.5s;
      opacity: 1;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    div.homepage-popular-categories p:before {
      content: '';
      display: inline-block;
      height: 100%;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    div.homepage-popular-categories p:hover {
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    }
    /*end banner overlay*/


    .new-arrivals{  
      background:url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/4f/a9/d1/4fa9d18c567a8c5a05997a9773685361.jpg') no-repeat; 
      width:313px;  
      height:313px;
    }

    .trending{
      background:url('http://socialmediaoutcomes.com/go/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/successful-business-people-smiling.jpg') no-repeat;  
      width:313px;  
      height:313px;

    }

    .shop-by-goal{
      background:url('https://brianpshea.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/4234255-group-of-business-people-smiling-together-in-an-office.jpg') no-repeat;    
      width:313px;  
      height:313px;

    }


    .strov-3-banners{   
        margin-top:15px;    
        text-align: center; 
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
        -ms-box-sizing: border-box; 
        -o-box-sizing: border-box;    
        box-sizing: border-box;    
        padding:10px 0;
    }
```

How do I get the the oval to be positioned correctly?

Comment: What you're looking for is how to vertically align multi-line text.

Comment: "round oval" is an oxymoron. Like a "square rectangle"

Comment: @j08691 You're right, didn't pay attention to that.

Comment: Your are missing the 'px' from your height rule

Comment: @JordanBarber I noticed, I fixed it. But it still won't center and the overlay is also off. https://jsfiddle.net/9f6xat3f/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round Border around text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36560830/round-border-around-text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a few amendments needed for `div.homepage-popular-categories p` selectors.

```
div.homepage-popular-categories p {
    position: absolute;
    color: #eeeeec;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: .5s;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    max-height: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

**Re-aligned Button:**

```css
.trending-button1{ 
border-radius: 25px;
border: 3px solid #fff;
padding: 20px;
width: 200px;
height: 50;
}

/*banner overlay*/
div.homepage-popular-categories {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.homepage-popular-categories p {
    position: absolute;
    color: #eeeeec;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: .5s;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    max-height: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

div.homepage-popular-categories p:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
div.homepage-popular-categories p:hover {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
/*end banner overlay*/


.new-arrivals{ 
  background:url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/4f/a9/d1/4fa9d18c567a8c5a05997a9773685361.jpg') no-repeat; 
  width:313px; 
  height:313px;
}

.trending{
  background:url('http://socialmediaoutcomes.com/go/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/successful-business-people-smiling.jpg') no-repeat; 
  width:313px; 
  height:313px;
  
}

.shop-by-goal{
  background:url('https://brianpshea.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/4234255-group-of-business-people-smiling-together-in-an-office.jpg') no-repeat; 
  width:313px; 
  height:313px;
  
}


.strov-3-banners{ 
 margin-top:15px; 
 text-align: center; 
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
 -ms-box-sizing: border-box; 
 -o-box-sizing: border-box;    
 box-sizing: border-box;    
 padding:10px 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="grid12-4 banner strov-3-banners shop-by-goal homepage-popular-categories ">
    <p>SHOP BY GOAL</p>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="#">
  <div class="grid12-4 banner strov-3-banners trending homepage-popular-categories ">
    <p>Shop Now</p>
    <p class="trending-button1">TRENDING </p>
  </div>
</a>


<a href="#">
  <div class="grid12-4 banner strov-3-banners new-arrivals homepage-popular-categories ">
    <p>NEW ARRIVALS</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

**Updated Fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/vct6dsu6/13/

---

**Fullcover overlay code snippet example:**

```css
div.homepage-popular-categories .trending-button1 {
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    max-height: 65px;
    margin: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 200px;
}

/*banner overlay*/
div.homepage-popular-categories {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.homepage-popular-categories p {
    position: absolute;
    color: #eeeeec;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: .5s;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

div.homepage-popular-categories p:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
div.homepage-popular-categories:hover p {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
/*end banner overlay*/


.new-arrivals{ 
  background:url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/4f/a9/d1/4fa9d18c567a8c5a05997a9773685361.jpg') no-repeat; 
  width:313px; 
  height:313px;
}

.trending{
  background:url('http://socialmediaoutcomes.com/go/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/successful-business-people-smiling.jpg') no-repeat; 
  width:313px; 
  height:313px;
  
}

.shop-by-goal{
  background:url('https://brianpshea.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/4234255-group-of-business-people-smiling-together-in-an-office.jpg') no-repeat; 
  width:313px; 
  height:313px;
  
}


.strov-3-banners{ 
 margin-top:15px; 
 text-align: center; 
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
 -ms-box-sizing: border-box; 
 -o-box-sizing: border-box;    
 box-sizing: border-box;    
 padding:10px 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="grid12-4 banner strov-3-banners shop-by-goal homepage-popular-categories ">
    <p>SHOP BY GOAL</p>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="#">
  <div class="grid12-4 banner strov-3-banners trending homepage-popular-categories ">
    <p>Shop Now</p>
    <p class="trending-button1">TRENDING </p>
  </div>
</a>


<a href="#">
  <div class="grid12-4 banner strov-3-banners new-arrivals homepage-popular-categories ">
    <p>NEW ARRIVALS</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

I'm not entirely sure what you plan on doing with the hover effects, so I'll leave that up to you to refine, but the snippet below will provide some examples to consider.

---

**Overlay hover effects**

Reveal and remove alternative on-hover demonstrations.

```css
div.homepage-popular-categories .trending-button1 {
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    max-height: 65px;
    margin: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 200px;
    background: transparent;
}

/*banner overlay*/
div.homepage-popular-categories {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.homepage-popular-categories p {
    position: absolute;
    color: #eeeeec;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: .5s;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

div.homepage-popular-categories p:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
div.homepage-popular-categories:hover p {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
/*end banner overlay*/


.new-arrivals{ 
  background:url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/4f/a9/d1/4fa9d18c567a8c5a05997a9773685361.jpg') no-repeat; 
  width:313px; 
  height:313px;
}

.trending{
  background:url('http://socialmediaoutcomes.com/go/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/successful-business-people-smiling.jpg') no-repeat; 
  width:313px; 
  height:313px;
  
}

.shop-by-goal{
  background:url('https://brianpshea.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/4234255-group-of-business-people-smiling-together-in-an-office.jpg') no-repeat; 
  width:313px; 
  height:313px;
  
}


.strov-3-banners{ 
 margin-top:15px; 
 text-align: center; 
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
 -ms-box-sizing: border-box; 
 -o-box-sizing: border-box;    
 box-sizing: border-box;    
 padding:10px 0;
}

/* On Hover Overlay Remove */
div.homepage-popular-categories.overlay-remove .trending-button1 {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

div.homepage-popular-categories.overlay-remove:hover .trending-button1 {
    margin-bottom: -150px;
}

div.homepage-popular-categories.overlay-remove {
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.homepage-popular-categories.overlay-remove:hover p {
    color: transparent;
}

/* On Hover Overlay Reveal */
div.homepage-popular-categories.overlay-reveal:hover p {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: #eeeeec;
}

div.homepage-popular-categories.overlay-reveal p {
    position: absolute;
    color: transparent;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    transition: .5s;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

div.homepage-popular-categories.overlay-reveal .trending-button1 {
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    max-height: 65px;
    margin: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: -150px;
}

div.homepage-popular-categories.overlay-reveal:hover .trending-button1 {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background: transparent;
}

div.homepage-popular-categories.overlay-reveal {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h2>Overlay Remove</h2>
<a href="#">
  <div class="grid12-4 banner strov-3-banners shop-by-goal homepage-popular-categories overlay-remove">
    <p>SHOP BY GOAL</p>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="#">
  <div class="grid12-4 banner strov-3-banners trending homepage-popular-categories overlay-remove">
    <p>Shop Now</p>
    <p class="trending-button1">TRENDING </p>
  </div>
</a>


<a href="#">
  <div class="grid12-4 banner strov-3-banners new-arrivals homepage-popular-categories overlay-remove">
    <p>NEW ARRIVALS</p>
  </div>
</a>

<hr>
<h2>Overlay Reveal</h2>
<a href="#">
  <div class="grid12-4 banner strov-3-banners shop-by-goal homepage-popular-categories overlay-reveal">
    <p>SHOP BY GOAL</p>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="#">
  <div class="grid12-4 banner strov-3-banners trending homepage-popular-categories overlay-reveal">
    <p>Shop Now</p>
    <p class="trending-button1">TRENDING </p>
  </div>
</a>


<a href="#">
  <div class="grid12-4 banner strov-3-banners new-arrivals homepage-popular-categories overlay-reveal">
    <p>NEW ARRIVALS</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks this looks really good but when you hover over the image the overlay is suppose to disappear entirely . In the "Fullcover overlay code snippet example" you provided the oval still contains an overlay.

Comment: Glad it helped. If you need the hover issue to be addressed as well you should mention it in the original question as well with the intended end result. Initially your question was the matter of alignment of the button in particular.

Comment: If you need the opaque background for the button to disappear on hover as well, it may be better to specify the `:hover` rule differently. E.g: `div.homepage-popular-categories:hover p {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}` The "Fullcover overlay code snippet example" has also been updated to demonstrate this.

Comment: The Shop Now text is still on top of the TRENDING text though. And also the Shop Now has an added overlayer that makes it seem darker than the rest of the div.

Comment: Overlay hover effects have been added to reveal or conceal the overlay alternatively. Note that you can position the button vertically by tweaking the top or bottom margins respectively; for example, if you need the button to appear above the text, use `margin-top` for natural and hover states instead of `margin-bottom`.

Comment: If you want to better position the text itself, without affecting the overly, consider wrapping the text and button in a parent element that you can attribute the overlay styles to instead, then you can make the text slide down, for example, from the top, as the button slides up from the bottom, while the background opaque overlay fades in simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

that would change the height of your box and align it center

```
    .trending-button1{  
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    max-height: 20px;
    margin:0 auto;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that did help but I the Shop Now is still not centered and the overlay is off too https://jsfiddle.net/9f6xat3f/1/

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to css , but you can make more. Why you style three times the boxes with height 313 and width 313 just add a class with same css attributes.

`.box {  width:313px;height:313px;}`

Take a look at this jsfiddle forked from you.

I reset the animations on hover but you can put it back.

[Look at this Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spyrosao/884tngsr/3/)